# Modelling interaction effects with interflex in STATA

Tags: interaction, stata

I am trying to model interaction effects with the *interflex* STATA package from Hainmueller et al. (2019). This is supposed to provide graphics to better gauge the robustness of interaction effects in regressions. In my case, I am interested in the effect of logFLOW (the moderator) on the effect of tw_TIES (the treatment) on mid_occ (the outcome). When attempting to use the interflex command, the following happens:

```
. interflex mid_occ tw_TIES logFLOW, vce(r) cut( -10 -5 0 5 10 15 20)
too many values
r(134);
```

For reference, "mid_occ" and "tw_TIES" are binary while "logFLOW" is continuous.
Replacing the binary with continous variables does not help, neither does using other interflex options like so:

```
. interflex mid_occ tw_TIES logFLOW, type(kernel)
too many values
r(134);
```

Reducing the number of observations has not helped either, I have gone down to below 70k form originally 1.5m.

The working example provided in the interflex package works fine:

```
. ssc install interflex, replace all
checking interflex consistency and verifying not already installed...
all files already exist and are up to date.

. use interflex_s3.dta, clear
(Written by R.              )

. interflex Y D X Z1, vce(r)
p value of Wald test: 0.0000

. interflex Y D X Z1, type(kernel)
Cross-validating bandwidth...
The optimal bandwidth is   0.5945

. 
end of do-file
```

The r(134) error description is as follows:

> 1) You attempted to encode a string variable that takes on
>       more than 65,536 unique values.  2) You attempted to tabulate
>       a variable or pair of variables that take on too many values.
>        If you specified two variables, try interchanging them.
>           3) You issued a graph command using the by option.  The
>           by-variable takes on too many different values to construct
>           a readable chart.

Which part of the error message is relevant here, definitely not the first one but the other two don't fit so well either? Do I still have too many observations? I am using the wrong types of variables?